# D3 chart to represent dependencies in layers

Tags: d3.js

I have a number of objects (services), with dependencies. I am able to represent this in D3 using a hierachical edge bundling diagram, which does represent dependencies but I would like represent with a bit of a sunburst type representation, with something like:

- objects that have no dependencies are shown in the center (core) / in an inner ring
- objects that depend on core directly are shown in a ring 1 layer out from inner
- objects that depend on 2nd layer are on 3rd layer, and so on...
- dependencies are represented by connecting lines (edge bundle style), not positional like sunburst.

Is this something that would be possible with D3? Anyone have any references if they've done something similar?

Comment: Radial tidy tree ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - yes, that looks perfect. Thank you. Post as a full answer, i will mark it as right